# When is a zero dimensional local ring a chain ring?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, local-rings

A commutative ring with identity is called a chain ring if all its ideals form a chain under inclusion. I want to know is there any proof for the fact that  **a zero dimensional local  ring is a chain ring whenever its maximal ideal is principal**?

Comment: This is proved in the paper : Hungerford, Thomas W.
On the structure of principal ideal rings.
Pacific J. Math. 25 1968 543–547.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A famous theorem by Kaplansky says that a commutative ring is a principal ideal ring iff all of its prime ideals are principal. By using a zero-dimensional local ring with a principal maximal ideal, you are in that situation.

A commutative, local principal ideal ring is well-known to be a chain ring (a.k.a. uniserial ring) as discussed [in the wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_ideal_ring#Structure_theory_for_commutative_PIR's).

Comment: Is its proof difficult?

Comment: @ArtorWaxsess Of the Cohen-Kaplansky theorem? I'm not familiar with the whole proof. I don't think it is too hard though. Check out  Irving Kaplansky, *Elementary divisors and modules*, Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 66 (1949), 464–491.
MR 0031470 (11,155b).  I'm not up to speed on the details for the second half, either. But they are both well-known and I suspect have been streamlined. And, for that matter, what I'm suggesting may be overkill, and there could be an alternative approach. This is just the first method I thought of.